# JavaFX requestFocus() deletes contents of TextField when opening with spacebar

Tags: java, javafx-2

I'm running into an issue with the `requestFocus()` method. Whenever I click on a link from a VBox table in my application, a details menu drops down indicating username etc which are editable. The problem is, when I open the link in the VBox using the spacebar, JavaFX puts a focus on the TextField, but highlights it. By the time I release the spacebar, the highlighted text is deleted.

Basically, when the TextField is given focus using a spacebar, the entire contents are highlighted and replaced with a space character. Pushing enter to open the link still highlights the text, but doesn't do anything else since it doesn't add any characters.

How do I make sure the text inside a TextField doesn't get highlighted?

Thanks.

Comment: Please include an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Your definition of the problem is clear enough, but without seeing an observable code it is hard to say or suggest something.

Comment: I wish I could show some code, I'm not exactly sure what I'm at liberty to do. One thing that semi-solved my problem was using the `deselect()` method. By running this on the TextField, I was able to unselect the text and pretty much just add a space to the beginning:

`nameTxt.getTextField().deselect()`

Answer (score 0):

The solution for TextField (entire content) doesn't get highlighted is adding the **.selectedEnd()** after the .requestFocus()

textField.requestFocus();
textField.selectEnd();

However, i'm not really sure for your case that deal with spacebar. Hope this help.